# Super Buggy Netbeans Issues

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

So I've been using NetBeans for a few months at my job. And there are some really egregious bugs that I just cannot believe are present in most people's versions.

My Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 (Build 201107282000)

So basically the there are two big bugs that annoy me daily. Number one, whenever I close a project in the projects tab. THe projects tab itself closes and I have to re-open it...
Number 2, whenever I open a file from a project. It opens in the same tab group as my projects, services, and files tabs. I then have to drag it into what I see to be the editor space to actually effectively edit it.

Has anyone else experienced problems like these? Like I said I doubt this is a problem with NetBeans itself...because I just don't see how an IDE that popular could have problems this big..I suspect its something to do with some settings somewhere..

Oh, I should also note that I am not the first user of this Windows installation, so there could be software conflicts going on that I'm unaware of....

Comment: It looks like the current Netbeans version is 7.2. Have you tried using a version that isn't a year old?

Comment: @mattb: The problems described are pretty big bugs to still be in anything calling itself version 7, even if it is a year old.

Comment: @mattb: Also, do you think Java itself has something to do with these bugs? (I ask because you are the one who added the Java tag. If the IDE had been coded in C++ instead of Java, would you have added C++ as a tag?)

Comment: I tagged it as Java since NetBeans is primarily a Java IDE and primarily used by Java developers, so putting that tag on it will help the best audience that can answer the question see it. Also the highness of the version number is irrelevant, any time someone encounters a bug in a piece of software and there is a newer version available the standard troubleshooting question is "did you try the newer version yet?"

Comment: All panels and windows are detachable. That can be confusing until you get familiar with the way it works. It's possible that you inadvertently dragged the main editor window into a side panel. NetBeans has many egregious bugs but its GUI is reasonably good.

Comment: ah I'm not a regular netbeans user and when I clicked update inside NetBeans it didn't find any...apologies for my ignorance. I'll try an update and see if that removes these annoyances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take Window-projects, and it comes in the left side over the source code page. There is an option (a square shaped button) at the top right corner, left to the close button, which is a "pin" option. It will attach the project tab permanently with the source.

Answer (score -3):

Please get the version NetBeans IDE 7.2. It is simply superb!It solved almost all issues which were present in the older version. Especially with Database and projects tab.

Comment: My experience contradicts this statement... NB is ridiculously buggy, SVN integration is a failure, preparing commit or show diff take ages, a bug that was reported multiple times but closed as a WONTFIX or not reproducible every time. Sometimes it makes it look a file was saved while it wasn't, and you end up losing changes: it's not only my experience but a problem we faced in my company which actually led to banning the use of NetBeans. I'm not saying that everybody will stumble on these issues, but I think it's enough to say it's not a superb IDE, at least not yet

Comment: @KonradMorawski it's now november 2013 and it's still buggy. I've given up and switched to sublime text 3

Comment: @bicycle I really like all the JetBrains' IDEs. I switched from NetBeans to PHPStorm for PHP and I'm using Android Studio for Java/Android. They're all based on the same engine and have the same feel. Thus I imagine that IntelliJ Idea (for "regular" Java) can't be bad either.

Comment: @KonradMorawski to be honest I just had it with all open source ide's. all are crap. Both eclipse and netbeans are disastrous. Try to install this: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/32782/lesscss-module you won't be able to. Maybe it will work on only one version that is only known to a select few (it's secret!). It reminds me to all the problems I had with Java with 999+ different frameworks that all work differently and have no docs (all are secret also). I think it's infectious to just Java. The only really good IDE i've used was Visual Studio though unfortunately php support is crappy :(